# I cant get past this 'NoneType' error in my bubblesort

Tags: python, recursion, bubble-sort

```
def bubble_sort(alist):
    size = len(alist)
    for i in range(size):
        index = alist[i]
        
        for j in range(size - 1, i, -1):
            if alist[j] < alist[j-1]:
                temp = alist[j-1]
                alist[j-1] = alist[j]
                alist[j] = temp         
       
    
def bsort(L):
    if len(L) <= 1:
        return L
    else:
        T = bubble_sort(L)
        if L[0] <= T[0]:
            return L[0] + T
        else:
            P = L[0] + T[-1]
            Q = bubble_sort(P)
        return T[0] + Q

print(bsort([5,4,3,9,1]))
```

Getting this error

```
    if L[0] <= T[0]:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: You are not returning anything from function `bubble_sort`.

Comment: So, you know the answer by now but a strategy to debug this for next time: `NoneType is not subscriptable` on that line of code means that either `L` is None or `T` is None. There's nothing else that can cause that error. So, print out both values before the `if` test, see which is None, and then work backwards through your code to see why it was not set correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning the result from `bubble_sort()` to `T`, but that function doesn't return anything explicitly, so it returns the default `None`:

```
T = bubble_sort(L)
```

So, when this line needs to be executed, you're indexing `T`, which is `None` - and `None` is not subscriptable:

```
    if L[0] <= T[0]:
```

Your code also has some type mismatch errors. As @M-Chen-3 points out, you're adding an integer to a list with:

```
            return L[0] + T
```

And here as well:

```
        return T[0] + Q
```

And here:

```
            P = L[0] + T[-1]
            Q = bubble_sort(P)
```

You are adding two integers, which results in an integer, but you then pass it to `bubble_sort()`, which expects a list.

Comment: Adding on to your answer, the lines `return L[0] + T` and `return T[0] + Q` will cause errors since you're adding integers to lists.